# Function in tidyverse

Tags: r

I want to create tidyverse with intermediate function.
I have a structure as

```
temp1 = sapply(df, function(x) .....)
temp2 = sapply(temp1, function(x) .......... )
temp3 = sapply(df, function(x) ..........)
temp = data.frame(temp2/temp3)
```

And I want to get something like this

```
sapply(df, function(x) .......) %>% sapply(df, function(x) ....... )
 %>% ......
```

Reproducible example:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(1,2,3))
temp1 = sapply(df, function(x) x*3)
temp2 = sapply(temp1, function(x) x+4 )
temp3 = sapply(df, function(x) x/4)
temp = data.frame(temp2/temp3)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could make this example specific with reproducible example and expected output.

Comment: @RonakShah I answered in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have more complicated functions to perform on every column than the one shown you could use `purrr` functions like :

```
library(purrr)

map2_df(map(df, ~.x * 3 + 4), map(df, ~.x/4), `/`)

#    a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1  28    28  
#2  20    20  
#3  17.3  17.3
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the pipe operator do not remember the first block of the chain, only the previous one, so you have to use an intermediate step.

However, you can simplify the first part of your code to a pipeline:

```
temp1 = df %>% sapply(function(x) x*3) %>% sapply(function(x) x+4)
temp = temp1/sapply(df, function(x) x/4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use brackets to wrap a whole pipe chain and use it as a data frame.

```
(df %>% sapply(., function(x) x*3) %>% sapply(., function(x) x+4 )) / 
  (df %>% sapply(., function(x) x/4) )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This answer seems very similar to another answer here. In the future when posting answers, make sure your answer contributes in a unique way to the question posed.